# Adding prefix to WooCommerce order number based on user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

I'm trying to change the WooCommerce order prefix based on user roles, Currently, this function work flawlessly :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $prefix = 'WHLS';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to change the order prefix based on user roles in the following way:
Export/Distributor Gold - GLD-###     (**new**)
Export/Distributor Silver - SLVR-###  (**new**)
Wholesale - WHLS-###  (**current functionality**)

**My attempted code:** (This function code does not add any prefix to the orders number).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );

function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'wholeseller' ))
    $prefix = 'WHLS';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
}
   
    if ( current_user_can( 'distributor_gold' )) {
    $prefix = 'GLD';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
    }
    

    elseif ( current_user_can( 'distributor_silver' )) {
    $prefix = 'SLVR';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;
    }
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$order->get_user()` to get the user associated with the order.

And then `$user->roles`, to get roles this user has.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_number( $order_number, $order ) {
    // Get user
    $user = $order->get_user();
    
    // Roles
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;
    
    // Compare
    if ( in_array ( 'wholeseller', $roles ) ) {
        $prefix = 'WHLS';
    } elseif ( in_array ( 'distributor_gold', $roles ) ) {
        $prefix = 'GLD';
    } elseif ( in_array ( 'distributor_silver', $roles ) ) {
        $prefix = 'SLVR';
    } elseif ( in_array ( 'administrator', $roles ) ) {
        $prefix = 'ADMIN';
    } else {
        $prefix = '';
    }
    
    return $prefix . $order_number;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'filter_woocommerce_order_number', 10, 2 );
```